# Reinstall GRUB after installing windows Vista

Tags: linux, operating-systems

I had two OS in laptop windows vista and linux mint and when I used to start my computer I used to get different option for os like linux mint, linux mint memory check, windows vista etc.. but because of virus windows vista got crashed so I formatted disk drive C: which were containing windows vista and reinstalled fresh copy of vista.. but now when I start my computer vista start automatically, I do not see GRUB options to run windows os or linux mint..

Is there a way to reinstall GRUB to get options like I used to get before formatting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot from Linux Live CD.
- Chroot to the Linux partition.
- Run grub-install again to update the MBR.